# The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable C#

Tags: c#

When I do this it says on the i % 3 that the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer but i is a variable. I tried changing some stuff, making i a var but it just keeps showing that problem

```
for(int i =0;i<100;i++)
{
    if(i % 3 = 0)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-comparison-operator

Comment: You need a double `=` sign for equality check. `if(i % 3 == 0)`

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, try `==`.

Answer (score 1):

sing "=" is for assignment.
double "=" is for comparison

your code should look like:

```
for(int i =0;i<100;i++)
    {
        if(i % 3 == 0)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the if statement, you need to use == to check for equality.

```
if(i % 3 == 0)
{
  // ...
}
```